# Calculate the intersection numbers by a plane section

Tags: algebraic-geometry, intersection-theory

This question is from the chapter A of Reid's note: *Chapters on algebraic surfaces*

> Let X = X$_d$ $\subset$ P$^3$ be a nonsingular surface of degree d and
>   suppose that X has a plane section P that decomposes as a union of two
>   curves P$\cap$X = A + B of degrees a and b. How to calculate the
>   intersection numbers A$^2$, B$^2$ and AB?

If possible, please do not use genus formula, because later there is a question ask me check it again with genus formula.

An added question: If the plane section has more than two parts, what can we say?

Comment: To get you started: do you see how to find $AB$ using Bezout?

Comment: Oh, yes, that is why we need X embeded in P$^3$, then the plane is P$^2$, Bezout can be used.

Comment: Good. Did you work out the complete answer?

Comment: I only try to do this with the genus formula and I am not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me sketch an answer here.

1. Since $A$ and $B$ are curves in the plane $P$, we get $A \cdot B = ab$ by Bézout.
2. Now since $A$ is contained in $X$, we have $A 
   \cdot (A+B) = A \cdot P$; to calculate this we can replace $P$ with a plane that meets $A$ *properly*, so we get $A \cdot P = a$.
3. Similarly for $B \cdot (A+B)$.

Combining the above gives the numbers $A^2$ and $B^2$.

Comment: As I know, the intersection number on the algebraic surface is "divisor intersect divisor", but P as a plane it not a divisor, so I do not know what is A·P，can you explain this or show me some references?

Comment: @Strongart: you can either think of $P$ as a plane in $\mathbf P^3$, so that $A \cdot P$ is an intersection of a curve and a divisor in 3-space, or think of $P$ as a plane section of $X$, in which case $A \cdot P$ means intersection of two curves on $X$. These two interpretations give the same answer.

Comment: If a line L in X, I can get L$^2$=2-d by genus formula. But in your way to do this, the result is independent with d, it is unbelievable!

Comment: @Strongart: yes, $L^2=2-d$ is correct. Why should it be independent of $d$?

Comment: It seems that self-intersection is dependent with the surface generally, line intersection has d, curve intersection are more general, so it is unbelievable without d. For a special case, A=L is line, then A$^2$=2-d, or there is no line in the place section?

Comment: I see，d=a+b, you are right.